# Perl code for inserting graphs into MS Word

Tags: perl, ms-word, svg, report

I am using Perl for automation for report generation. Reports are generated in HTML. same report can be opened in MS word format. tables generated in HTML look good in Word too.

#### Problem:

Ineed to also insert few graphs in the report. For HTML, I am using [SVG::TT::Graph::Line](http://metacpan.org/module/SVG%3a%3aTT%3a%3aGraph%3a%3aLine) Perl module to generate the graphs.

The idea here is to keep single HTML file that contains all tables and graphs.

Currently every thing looks good in HTML. but when i open the same file in Word, the graphs are replaced by data (because I am using SVG Perl module).

Just wondering what would be the best way to generate graphs for Word file that doesn't change my code much.

Any suggestions with the Perl modules to be used would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but the only thing I can think of is to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to convert the SVG to PNG and then use a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to embed the image in the HTML.